# Using JCloud Compute API with KVM

Tags: java, git, kvm, hypervisor, jclouds

I want to use jclouds compute api for managing virtual machines virtiualized via KVM hypervisor. AFAIK compute api supports apis like Openstack ,abiquo ,which wraps hypervisor apis. However i want to manage KVM directly like [libvirt](http://libvirt.org/) api. I know in jclouds repository there is [sandbox-api](https://github.com/rstradling/jclouds/tree/master/sandbox-apis/libvirt), which contains libvirt bindings. However it seems it is not in the main repository and while building the code i get compile error due to version conflicts. I want to know whether there is an offical location for the libvirt bindings in the jcloud repository?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official location for such APIs is [jclouds-labs](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-labs). If that libvirt API were to become part of jclouds, it would need to have a contributor willing to maintain it and be submitted to jclouds-labs initially.

Source: I'm a jclouds committer and PMC member.

Comment: I see, so the api need to be commited to the jcloud-labs in order to become offical. How about legacy-jclouds-labs? What is the difference between the two repositories. If one want to contribute ,from which repository needs to be forked?

Comment: You can safely ignore legacy-jclouds-labs. It's there for historical purposes only from our pre-Apache days. [jclouds-labs](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-labs) is the way forward and you would want to fork from there. You might also want to read about [How to Contribute to jclouds](https://wiki.apache.org/jclouds/How%20to%20Contribute).